# Firebase Authentication callback not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

> **signInWithEmailAndPassword** calls but doesn't return any `callback` for `addOnFailureListener` or `addOnCompleteListener`

What am i doing wrong.?? 
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip` in **gradle-wrapper.properties** is up to date..

**AppGradle**

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Project Level Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "firebase.learning"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
// Add to the bottom of the file
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**SignInActivity.class**

```
public class SignInActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "SignInActivity";
    private EditText inputEmail, inputPassword;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private Button btnSignup, btnLogin, btnReset;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Get Firebase auth instance
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(SignInActivity.this, AddQuestionActivity.class));
            finish();
        }

        // set the view now
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);

        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    //redirect
                    ///updateUI(user);

                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                    ///updateUI(null);
                }

            }
        };

        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        btnSignup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        btnReset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_reset_password);

        //Get Firebase auth instance
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        btnSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ///startActivity(new Intent(SignInActivity.this, AddQuestionActivity.class));
            }
        });

        btnReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ///startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ResetPasswordActivity.class));
            }
        });

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                final String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
                        .addOnFailureListener(SignInActivity.this, new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this,"Failure",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnCompleteListener(SignInActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:success");
                                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                                    ///updateUI(user);

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(SignInActivity.this, AddQuestionActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                } else {
                                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                                    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                                    Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    ///updateUI(null);
                                }
                            }
                        });

                //authenticate user
                /*auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(SignInActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                                // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                                // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    // there was an error
                                    if (password.length() < 6) {
                                        inputPassword.setError("Password too short, enter minimum 6 characters!");
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Authentication failed, check your email and password or sign up", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(SignInActivity.this, AddQuestionActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                }
                            }
                        });*/
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mAuthListener != null) {
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try debug the code

Comment: I tried but callback is not returning.

Comment: using breakpoints?

Comment: are you sure `mAuth.addAuthStateListener` currectly run in `onStart()`?

Comment: Yes it is working but none of the callback return

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, please also add in your `build.gradle` file the following dependency:

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
```

From the official documentation:

> Your app gradle file now has to explicitly list `com.google.firebase:firebase-core` as a dependency for Firebase services to work as expected.

Don't also forget to add in your top level `build.gradle` file the following Google Service plugin:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
```